# Issue with servo motor and potentiometer: not moving when program is inserted into board

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32, mbed

This code is meant to utilize a potentiometer to turn a servomotor. When I tried to insert it into the program the servo didn't move at all, and I don't know if it is a result of my board, my wiring, or my code. If anyone could help or provide some assistance to the matter, it would much be appreciated. The board I am using is a Nucleo STM L476RG board and the motor is a micro SG90.

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Servo.h"
#include "iostream"

Servo myservo(D6);
AnalogOut MyPot(A1);


int main() {
    float PotReading;
    PotReading = MyPot.read();

    while(1) {
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            myservo.SetPosition(PotReading);
            wait(0.01);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the code I was using had this code in the published library servo listed as Servo.h

```
#ifndef MBED_SERVO_H
#define MBED_SERVO_H

#include "mbed.h"

/** Class to control a servo on any pin, without using pwm
 *
 * Example:
 * @code
 * // Keep sweeping servo from left to right
 * #include "mbed.h"
 * #include "Servo.h"
 * 
 * Servo Servo1(p20);
 *
 * Servo1.Enable(1500,20000);
 *
 * while(1) {
 *     for (int pos = 1000; pos < 2000; pos += 25) {
 *         Servo1.SetPosition(pos);  
 *         wait_ms(20);
 *     }
 *     for (int pos = 2000; pos > 1000; pos -= 25) {
 *         Servo1.SetPosition(pos); 
 *         wait_ms(20); 
 *     }
 * }
 * @endcode
 */

class Servo {

public:
    /** Create a new Servo object on any mbed pin
     *
     * @param Pin Pin on mbed to connect servo to
     */
    Servo(PinName Pin);

    /** Change the position of the servo. Position in us
     *
     * @param NewPos The new value of the servos position (us)
     */
    void SetPosition(int NewPos);

    /** Enable the servo. Without enabling the servo won't be running. Startposition and period both in us.
     *
     * @param StartPos The position of the servo to start (us) 
     * @param Period The time between every pulse. 20000 us = 50 Hz(standard) (us)
     */
    void Enable(int StartPos, int Period);

    /** Disable the servo. After disabling the servo won't get any signal anymore
     *
     */
    void Disable();

private:
    void StartPulse();
    void EndPulse();

    int Position;
    DigitalOut ServoPin;
    Ticker Pulse;
    Timeout PulseStop;
};

#endif
```

It also had a .cpp file in the same place as it so if anyone needs it as a reference I'll post it as an edit. I will also put the wiring just in case

The servo is an [SG90](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/DE1_EE/stores/sg90_datasheet.pdf).

The wiring of the board:
[image]

Comment: Should your potentiometer be an `AnalogIn`? You also likely want to read the pot input on every loop iteration. Right now you're just reading it once at the start of the program and never again. You turn it into a useless knob immediately after starting the program.

Comment: @JohnFilleau just changed it and tested it, the same result as before

Comment: And a fourth problem: `Servo::SetPosition` expects an `int` between `0` and (likely) `20000` (depending on the spec sheet of your particular servo). `AnalogIn::read` returns a `float` between `0` and `1`. You'll need to convert that float to the int.

Comment: @GB "just changed it and tested it" changed it to *what*? Tested it *how*? You have several errors in here and they all need to be addressed.

Comment: Right now you have several moving pieces. You have a potentiometer that generates a voltage. That is read by your ADC. That is then read by your ADC driver. That is then written to your Servo. Do you have a multimeter? Start at the beginning. Make sure twisting the pot actually causes the voltage to deviate. If it does, then move to the next one. Is there some debugging interface with these chips that allow you to single step through code?

Comment: Are there any other problems? Also wrote that comment when I saw the AnalogIn post.

Comment: Also please provide the datasheet for your servo.

Comment: Reposting this because someone didn't like my initialization, which I don't blame them for. You need to call `Servo::Enable`. From the documentation: *"Enable the servo. Without enabling the servo won't be running."*

Comment: Here: http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/DE1_EE/stores/sg90_datasheet.pdf

Comment: Okay good. According to the datasheet this servo is standard 50 Hz duty cycle. The example in your library header should get you on the right track then.

Comment: Voltage Check Clear

Comment: I posted the closest I could get to an answer given the information we have. If you end up changing your code and want feedback, please please please do not change the original code in your question. Instead edit your question with a section at the end showing your updated code, clearly labeled as updated.

Comment: A schematic would be better than a photo, but if you have issues with the physical implementation rather then the software then https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ is where you need to ask.  The wiring looks _plausible_ at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is how the servo motor works.  From the data sheet it requires a 50Hz PWM with a pulse width from 1 to 2ms.  The pulse width determines the position, so a width of 1ms will position the servo at one end of its travel, a pulse of 2ms will set the position at the other end, and 1.5ms will set the centre position.

Second you need to read the documentation (in the comments) for the `Servo` class you are using. It even has example code.  First you need to instantiate a `Servo` object (which you have done), then you need to Enable it by setting its pulse interval and initial pulse width (or position):

```
Servo output( D6 ) ;
output.Enable( 1500, 20000 ) ; // Centre position, 50Hz
```

Then if you want to read an analogue input, clearly you need an `AnalogIn` object:

```
AnalogOut input(A1);
```

Then you need to understand that a *closed-loop* control system must continuously read its input to adjust the output.  Here you only read the potentiometer once *before* the control loop, so in the loop it never changes value so the position will not change.  Moreover you have an entirely unnecessary inner loop that appears for come from the example code for an entirely different `Servo` implementation [here](https://os.mbed.com/users/simon/code/Servo/docs/tip/classServo.html) - that example was not a closed-loop control system - it simply continuously cycles the servo back-and forth over its full range - that is not what you are trying to achieve in this case and it is just [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

In *closed-loop control* you *continuously*:

```
         _______
        |       |
        V       |
    get-input   | <repeat>
    set-output  |
        |_______|
```

Finally you need to understand that the units of the input measurement in this case are not the same as the units of the output setting - they need scaling so that the full scale input range maps to the full scale output range. The mbed [`AnalogIn`](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.15/apis/analogin.html) class has two read functions; `AnalogIn::read()` returns a `float` in the range 0.0 to 1.0 and `AnalogIn::read_u16` returns an `uint16_t` value 0 to 65535.  Personally I'd use the integer version, but the STM32F4 parts have a single precision FPU, so the lack of hardware floating point is not an issue in this case - although there are other reasons for avoiding floating point.  Then the `Servo::setPosition()` function takes a position argument in terms of the pulse width, and as explained above this relates to a position scale 0 to 20000 given the suggested initialisation.  So you need either:

```
float set_point = input.read() ;
output.SetPosition( (int)( (set_point * 1000) + 1000 ) ; // Scale to 1 to 2ms
```

or

```
uint16_t set_point = input.read_u16() ;
output.SetPosition( ((set_point * 1000) >> 16) + 1000 ) ;
```

Putting all that together (with a few other refinements):

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Servo.h"

int main() 
{
    // Hardware parameters
    static const int SERVO_FREQ = 50 ;                        // Hz
    static const int SERVO_PERIOD = 1000000 / SERVO_FREQ ;    // microseconds
    static const int SERVO_MIN = 1000 ;                       // 1ms in microseconds
    static const int SERVO_MAX = 2000 ;                       // 2ms in microseconds
    static const int SERVO_RANGE = SERVO_MAX  - SERVO_MIN ;

    // I/O configuration
    AnalogIn input( A1 ) ;
    Servo output( D6 ) ;
    output.Enable( SERVO_MIN, SERVO_PERIOD ) ;

    // Control loop
    for(;;)
    {
        float set_point = input.read() ;                            // 0.0 to 1.0
        output.SetPosition( set_point * SERVO_RANGE + SERVO_MIN ) ; // 1 to 2ms

        wait_us( SERVO_PERIOD ) ; // wait for one complete PWM cycle.
    }
}
```

The *fixed point* version would have:

```
        uint16_t set_point = input.read_u16() ;                 // 0 to 2^16
        output.SetPosition( ((set_point * SERVO_RANGE) >> 16)   // 1 to 2ms
                            + SERVO_MIN ) ;
```

in the loop.

Note that this is not the most elegant `Servo` class implementation. It is little more than a PWM class.  It would be better if the min/max pulse width were passed to the constructor along with the period so that you could just give it a zero to *n* set-point rather than an absolute pulse width.  That way the somewhat arcane output value calculation would be simplified because the `Servo` class would do that for you with suitable range checks.  In fact if the position parameter were a `uint16_t` and the range 0 to 65535, then all possible input values would be valid and you could pass the output of `AnalogIn::read_u16()` to it directly so your loop could just contain:

```
output.SetPosition_u16( input.read_u16() ) ;
wait_us( SERVO_PERIOD ) ;
```

In other words - get a better `Servo` class or write your own - this is doing little for you in terms of encapsulating servo control expertise.

Answer (score 1):

### Immediate observations

I see five issues right now, ranging from "maybe a problem" to "likely a problem". I was able to make out the pin labels on your photograph, and your pin assignments appear to be correct. Assuming there's no weird wire or voltage issues:

1. Your analog pin should be an `AnalogIn`, not an `AnalogOut`. While `AnalogOut` has the ability to `read`, that's used for feedback to make sure that your output is what you expect it to be. Right now, as an `AnalogOut`, you're actually acting as a voltage source on this pin and *setting* the voltage instead of *measuring* the voltage.
2. You're not calling `Servo::Enable`. The documentation tells you how to call `Servo::Enable`. Make sure to call it. You are even required to specify a starting position for the servo, and this will allow you to troubleshoot your output and servo (see troubleshooting later).
3. `AnalogIn::read` returns a `float` between `[0.0, 1.0]` to represent the ratio between the voltage read on the input line and the system voltage (5V or 3.3V usually). However, `Servo::SetPosition` expects an integer that represents the length (as an `int` in microseconds - between 0 and 20,000 in your case) of the positive part of the pulse signal. If you try to pass the result of `AnalogIn::read` to `Servo::SetPosition`, then your `float` will be converted to a 0 (except for the one single rare case when it's `1`). You need to translate your analog input into an integer output.
4. Right now in your code you're only reading the status of the analog input pin at the very start of your program. You enter an infinite loop and never read this analog input again. You can twist that knob to your heart's content but it will never affect the program. You need to read the analog input many times. Move this inside of your loop.
5. Just a style thing, but you don't need that inner `for` loop. It doesn't do anything except clutter your code. If you're expecting to use the value of `i` at some point in the future then leave this in, but otherwise ditch it.

### Troubleshooting

Luckily, many systems can be thought of as many boxes (subsystems) with arrows drawn between them. If all the boxes are doing their job correctly and they're plugged into the correct next box, then the entire system as a whole works. Your system looks like this:

```
+-----+   +-----+   +----------------+   +-------------+   +--------------------+   +-----+   +-------+
| Pot |-->| ADC |-->| AnalogIn::read |-->| Float-to-us |-->| Servo::SetPosition |-->| PWM |-->| Servo |
+-----+   +-----+   +----------------+   +-------------+   +--------------------+   +-----+   +-------+
```

All together these subsystems form your entire system. If one of these links isn't working correctly, the whole thing won't work correctly. Usually (or at least we like to imagine we will when we have the time), we apply tests to systems and subsystems to make sure that they produce expected output depending on their input. If you apply input to one of those boxes, and the output is what you expect, then that box is good. Give it a green check mark and move to the next one.

Testing for each of these could be something like:

1. **Potentiometer:** *input:* twist the knob, *output:* the voltage at the middle pin as near system voltage (5V or 3.3V) when turned all the way one way, close to 0 when turned to the opposite end, and has approximately linear progression between the two ends. You'll need a multimeter to measure this.
2. **ADC (analog-to-digital converter):** *input:* some voltage on the input pin. You can vary this by twisting the potentiometer, once you verify that's working. *output:* this is a little harder because the output is a register in the microcontroller. I don't know what the debugging environment looks like for your hardware, so I can't tell you how to measure this output. You can *assume* this works and move onto the next one if you don't know how to use the debugger (but you really should learn how to use your hardware's debugger)
3. **`AnalogIn::read`:** *input:* a register value of the ADC. *output:* some float between 0.0 and 1.0. We can test the ADC and the `AnalogIn::read` function at the same time by treating them as one subsystem, with pin voltage as the input and a float value as the output. Again for this you'll need some debugging functionality. Either print statements or a serial connection or a development environment or something.
4. **Float to us conversion:** *input:* a float between 0.0 and 1.0. *output:* an integer between 0 and 20,000, proportional (or inversely proportional, depending on desired functionality) to the float input. Again, since we're looking at variables, you'll need to use your debugging environment.
5. **`Servo::SetPosition`** *input:* an integer between 0 and 20,000 representing the duty cycle (high period) of your output pulse width modulated (PWM) signal. *output:* increasing this number increases the observed duty cycle. Decreasing decreases it. The length of the duty cycle in us is about equal to the set length in code. You'll need an oscilloscope to observe the duty cycle. Alternatively, if your servo is working, then you should see it move when this changes.
6. **Servo:** *input:* a PWM signal. *output:* an angular position. A 0% duty cycle should be all the way to one extreme, and a 100% duty cycle should be rotated to the other extreme.

### Conclusion

Treat your system as a series of subsystems. Test each one independently. You can't expect the next subsystem to "make up for" the inadequacies of the one before it. They all need to work.